# GraphQL Angular : Query result mapping

Tags: angular, graphql

Having

```js
public getDoseStacked(param: String) : Observable<DoseStackedApi> {
return this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({
        query: this.STACKED,
        variables: {
          param : param
        }
    }).valueChanges
    .pipe(
      map(result => {
        // 1
        console.log(">> result.data = " + JSON.stringify(result.data));
        // 2
        console.log(">> result.data.doseStackedApi= " + JSON.stringify(result.data.doseStackedApi));
        return result.data.doseStackedApi;
      }
      ));
    }
```

With Query defined as follow :

```js
export type Query = {
  doseStackedApi : DoseStackedApi;
};

export type DoseStackedApi = {
  periods   : string[];
  areas     : DoseStackedMap[];
  columns   : DoseStackedMap[];
};

export type DoseStackedMap = {
  doseName  : string;
  items     : DoseStackedDto[];
};

export type DoseStackedDto = {
  period    : string;
  totalDose : number;
};
```

The log [1] display:

```
result.data = {"doseStacked":{"__typename":"DoseStackedApi",
"periods":["2020-12-28","2021-01-04"],
"areas":[{"__typename":"DoseStackedMap","doseName":"1",
"items":[{"__typename":"DoseStackedDto","totalDose":0,"period":"2020-12-28"},...
```

But log [2] display `result.data.doseStackedApi = undefined` while I would have expect :

```
result.data.doseStackedApi = "periods":["2020-12-28","2021-01-04"],"areas":
[{"__typename":"DoseStackedMap","doseName":"1","items":
[{"__typename":"DoseStackedDto","totalDose":0,"period":"2020-12-28"},
...
```

What could be possibly wrong ?

Comment: What is `this.STACKED`?

Comment: Please see the answer below, found the problem. Thanks asking !

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Your original code probably would also work if you alias your `STACKED` query with `doseStackedApi` fyi. (https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. In case someone face the same problem, `Query` must have a member variable name mathing in this case the query name in STACKED, that is `doseStacked`:

STACKED:

```
STACKED  = gql`
query STACKED($param: String!) {
  doseStacked(param: $param)
..
}`;
```

So `Query` must look as follow (guessing for graphql to be able map the result while unmarshalling):

```
export type Query = {
  doseStacked: DoseStackedApi; //instead of doseStackedApi 
};
```